# Python - Can't Get Counter To Work in Multiprocessing Environment (Pool, Map)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, counter

I need the counter variable (list_counter) inside my 'scraper' function to increment for each iteration through list1.

The problem is it's assigning a counter **to each individual process**.

I want each process to simply increment the global list_counter at the end of the loop, not for each process to have its own counter.

I tried passing the variable as an argument but couldn't get it to work that way either.

What you guys think? Is it even possible to have a global counter work with multiple processes - specifically using pool, map, lock?

```
from multiprocessing import Lock, Pool
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

exceptions = []
lock = Lock()
list_counter = 0


def scraper(url):  # url is tied to the individual list items
    """
    Testing multiprocessing and requests
    """

    global list_counter

    lock.acquire()

    try:

        scrape = requests.get(url,
                              headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36"},
                              timeout=10)

        if scrape.status_code == 200:

            """ --------------------------------------------- """
            # ---------------------------------------------------
            '''           --> SCRAPE ALEXA RANK: <--          '''
            # ---------------------------------------------------
            """ --------------------------------------------- """

            sleep(0.1)
            scrape = requests.get("http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=s&url=" + url,
                                  headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36"})
            html = scrape.content
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

            rank = re.findall(r'<popularity[^>]*text="(\d+)"', str(soup))

            print("Server Status:", scrape.status_code, '-', u"\u2713", '-', list_counter, '-', url, '-', "Rank:", rank[0])

            list_counter = list_counter + 1

        else:
            print("Server Status:", scrape.status_code)
            list_counter = list_counter + 1
            print(list_counter)
            pass

    except BaseException as e:
        exceptions.append(e)
        print()
        print(e)
        print()
        list_counter = list_counter + 1
        print(list_counter)
        pass

    finally:
        lock.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    list1 = ["http://www.wallstreetinvestorplace.com/2018/04/cvs-health-corporation-cvs-to-touch-7-54-earnings-growth-for-next-year/",
             "https://macondaily.com/2018/04/06/cetera-advisors-llc-lowers-position-in-cvs-health-cvs.html",
             "http://www.thesportsbank.net/football/liverpool/jurgen-klopp-very-positive-about-mo-salah-injury/",
             "https://www.moneyjournals.com/trump-wasting-time-trying-bring-amazon/",
             "https://www.pmnewsnigeria.com/2018/04/06/fcta-targets-800000-children-for-polio-immunisation/",
             "http://toronto.citynews.ca/2018/04/06/officials-in-canada-braced-for-another-spike-in-illegal-border-crossings/",
             "https://www.pmnewsnigeria.com/2018/04/04/pdp-describes-looters-list-as-plot-to-divert-attention/",
             "https://beyondpesticides.org/dailynewsblog/2018/04/epa-administrator-pruitt-colluding-regulated-industry/",
             "http://thyblackman.com/2018/04/06/robert-mueller-is-searching-for/",
             "https://www.theroar.com.au/2018/04/06/2018-commonwealth-games-swimming-night-2-finals-live-updates-results-blog/",
             "https://medicalresearch.com/pain-research/migraine-linked-to-increased-risk-of-heart-disease-and-stroke/40858/",
             "http://www.investingbizz.com/2018/04/amazon-com-inc-amzn-stock-creates-investors-concerns/",
             "https://stocknewstimes.com/2018/04/06/convergence-investment-partners-llc-grows-position-in-amazon-com-inc-amzn.html",
             "https://factsherald.com/old-food-rules-needs-to-be-updated/",
             "https://www.nextadvisor.com/blog/2018/04/06/the-facebook-scandal-evolves/",
             "http://sacramento.cbslocal.com/2018/04/04/police-family-youtube-shooter/",
             "http://en.brinkwire.com/245768/why-does-stress-lead-to-weight-gain-study-sheds-light/",
             "https://www.marijuana.com/news/2018/04/monterey-bud-jeff-sessions-is-on-the-wrong-side-of-history-science-and-public-opinion/",
             "http://www.stocksgallery.com/2018/04/06/jpmorgan-chase-co-jpm-noted-a-price-change-of-0-80-and-amazon-com-inc-amzn-closes-with-a-move-of-2-92/",
             "https://stocknewstimes.com/2018/04/06/front-barnett-associates-llc-has-2-41-million-position-in-cvs-health-corp-cvs.html",
             "http://www.liveinsurancenews.com/colorado-mental-health-insurance-bill-to-help-consumers-navigate-the-system/",
             "http://newyork.cbslocal.com/2018/04/04/youtube-headquarters-shooting-suspect/",
             "https://ledgergazette.com/2018/04/06/liberty-interactive-co-series-a-liberty-ventures-lvnta-shares-bought-by-brandywine-global-investment-management-llc.html",
             "http://bangaloreweekly.com/2018-04-06-city-holding-co-invests-in-cvs-health-corporation-cvs-shares/",
             "https://www.thenewsguru.com/didnt-know-lawyer-paid-prostitute-130000-donald-trump/",
             "http://www.westlondonsport.com/chelsea/football-wls-conte-gives-two-main-reasons-chelseas-loss-tottenham",
             "https://registrarjournal.com/2018/04/06/amazon-com-inc-amzn-shares-bought-by-lenox-wealth-management-inc.html",
             "http://www.businessdayonline.com/1bn-eca-withdrawal-commence-action-president-buhari-pdp-tasks-nass/",
             "http://www.thesportsbank.net/football/manchester-united/pep-guardiola-asks-for-his-fans-help-vs-united-in-manchester-derby/",
             "https://www.pakistantoday.com.pk/2018/04/06/three-palestinians-martyred-as-new-clashes-erupt-along-gaza-border/",
             "http://www.nasdaqfortune.com/2018/04/06/risky-factor-of-cvs-health-corporation-cvs-is-observed-at-1-03/",
             "https://stocknewstimes.com/2018/04/06/cetera-advisor-networks-llc-decreases-position-in-cvs-health-cvs.html",
             "http://nasdaqjournal.com/index.php/2018/04/06/planet-fitness-inc-nyseplnt-do-analysts-think-you-should-buy/",
             "http://www.tv360nigeria.com/apc-to-hold-national-congress/",
             "https://www.pmnewsnigeria.com/2018/04/03/apc-governors-keep-sealed-lips-after-meeting-with-buhari/",
             "https://www.healththoroughfare.com/diet/healthy-lifestyle-best-foods-you-should-eat-for-weight-loss/7061",
             "https://stocknewstimes.com/2018/04/05/amazon-com-inc-amzn-shares-bought-by-west-oak-capital-llc.html",
             "http://www.current-movie-reviews.com/48428/dr-oz-could-you-be-a-victim-of-sexual-assault-while-on-vacation/",
             "https://www.brecorder.com/2018/04/07/410124/world-health-day-to-be-observed-on-april-7/",
             "http://www.coloradoindependent.com/169637/trump-pruitt-emissions-epa-pollution",
             "https://thecrimereport.org/2018/04/05/will-sessions-new-justice-strategy-turn-the-clock-back-on-civil-rights/",
             "http://en.brinkwire.com/245490/pasta-unlikely-to-cause-weight-gain-as-part-of-a-healthy-diet/"]

    p = Pool(15)  # thread count
    p.map(scraper, list1)  # (function, iterable)
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Processes do not share memory so there is no straightforward way to do what you want.  However in the multiprocessing module there are objects called Managers that can be used for this sort of purpose.  They are described (not very clearly IMO) in the standard library docs, and their correct use is a challenge.  But that's the tool you need here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use concurrent.futures

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests


def scraper(url):
    list_counter = 0
    try:
        scrape = requests.get(url,
                              headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36"},
                              timeout=10)
        if scrape.status_code == 200:

            sleep(0.1)
            scrape = requests.get("http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=s&url=" + url,
                                  headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36"})
            html = scrape.content
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

            rank = re.findall(r'<popularity[^>]*text="(\d+)"', str(soup))

            print("Server Status:", scrape.status_code, '-', u"\u2713", '-', list_counter, '-', url, '-', "Rank:", rank[0])

            list_counter = list_counter + 1

        else:
            print("Server Status:", scrape.status_code)
            list_counter = list_counter + 1
            print(list_counter)
            pass

    except BaseException as e:
        exceptions.append(e)
        print()
        print(e)
        print()
        list_counter = list_counter + 1
        print(list_counter)
        pass

def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()
```

list1 copy your list here(in order to save space)

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 50): url for url in list1}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for n, p in zip(list1, executor.map(scraper, list1)):
            print(n, p)
```

You will get output(just a few lines)

```
http://www.coloradoindependent.com/169637/trump-pruitt-emissions-epa-pollution None
Server Status: 200 - ✓ - 0 - https://thecrimereport.org/2018/04/05/will-sessions-new-justice-strategy-turn-the-clock-back-on-civil-rights/ - Rank: 381576
https://thecrimereport.org/2018/04/05/will-sessions-new-justice-strategy-turn-the-clock-back-on-civil-rights/ None
Server Status: 200 - ✓ - 0 - http://en.brinkwire.com/245490/pasta-unlikely-to-cause-weight-gain-as-part-of-a-healthy-diet/ - Rank: 152818
http://en.brinkwire.com/245490/pasta-unlikely-to-cause-weight-gain-as-part-of-a-healthy-diet/ None
```

Answer (score 0):

Process do not share memory between them. But you can use [Manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) of the multiprocessing module so the process can manipulate the same object:

```
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
list_counter = manager.list()
```

You will have to pass the list_counter to the scraper function.
Note the list created by the manager is thread/process safe.